# How to track site searches in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, site-search

I would like to set up search queries in Google Analytics to have stats of site searches, however it doesn't seem to show me any stats. This is what I have entered so far:

[image: GA]

On my site, searching (or getting search results) can be done in a couple ways - simple and rewritten. Here are examples of that:

`http://example.com/?search=mobile+phone`

`http://example.com/search/mobile%20phone/date/1.html`

What do I need to enter into the fields to have my searches tracked correctly in Google Analytics?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that Google Analytics only supports query string parameters for these fields. So, you should simply enter the value `search` (without an equals sign). It does not support regular expressions, or any other form of URL.

Personally, I would argue against using "pretty URLs" (e.g. "/search/mobile%20phone/date/1.html") for search queries. But, if you do want to use them, you can override the URL in the Javascript code:

`ga('send', 'pageview', '/?search=mobile+phone');`

([Source](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/pages)).

You could of course place regular expressions here, and rewrite accordingly, but I will leave the implementation to you.